# Split main list into multiple dictionary keys and values in Python

Tags: python, list, parsing, dictionary, split

I am trying to split a list into a dictionary with multiple keys and corresponding values. I am not sure if this is possible. But basically I am trying to parse a list and based on certain conditions, I want to put following items into their respective keys

Input list:

```
inputlist = ['example line begin','C40 D50','H4000 J30','; condition
1','E40 R50','G009 J56798','RFG50 F400','; condition 2','BG3400
F5600','C40 DH4000 J3F0','C40 D50','; condition 1','T40 R50','G009
J56798','RFG50 F400','condition3....]
```

Expected Output Dictionary:

```
newDict = {'condition1':['E40 R50','G009 J56798','RFG50
F400'],'condition2':['BG3400 F5600','C40 DH4000 J3F0','C40 D50'],
'condition3':['........}
```

I also want to store the initial section that remained unused. I am not sure how to approach this problem as it feels like I need to set multiple flags to toggle On/off

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
ozpattern = re.compile(r";\scondtion1")
outerpattern = re.compile(r";\scondition2")
ozFlag = False
outerFlag = False

for line in inputlist:

    ozmatch = ozpattern.search(line)
    outermatch = outerpattern.search(line)

    if ozmatch:
        ozFlag = True
        ozKey = ''.join(ozmatch[2:].split(' '))
        outerFlag = False

    if ozFlag == True:
        newDict[ozKey].append(line)

    if outermatch:
        outerKey = ''.join(outertempmatch[2:].split(' '))
        ozFlag = False
        outerFlag = True
        continue

    if outertempmatch:
        newDict[outerKey].append(line)
```

But I am stuck here, as I need to set flags for few different conditions here and it can get tedious.

Comment: This looks a lot like your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387498/parsing-text-file-and-segregating-the-data-in-a-dictionary

Comment: @ PaulMcG,kappa, and asked by the same person

Comment: @PaulMcG  I apologize. I intended to ask a different question but ended up asking the same one. 
I wanted to read the output value into multiple dictionaries (if a condition is met)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
inputlist = ['example line begin','C40 D50','H4000 J30','; condition 1','E40 R50','G009 J56798','RFG50 F400','; condition 2','BG3400 F5600','C40 DH4000 J3F0','C40 D50','; condition 3','T40 R50','G009J56798','RFG50 F400']
initialList = []
newDict = {}
key = ''
for i in inputlist:
    m = re.match('; (.*)', i)
    if m:
        key = m.group(1)
    elif key:
        newDict.setdefault(key, []).append(i)
    else:
        initialList.append(i)
print(initialList)
print(newDict)
```

This outputs:

```
['example line begin', 'C40 D50', 'H4000 J30']
{'condition 1': ['E40 R50', 'G009 J56798', 'RFG50 F400'], 'condition 2': ['BG3400 F5600', 'C40 DH4000 J3F0', 'C40 D50'], 'condition 3': ['T40 R50', 'G009J56798', 'RFG50 F400']}
```

Comment: `if i.startswith(';'):` would be much simpler - only resort to regex when simple str methods won't cut it. `defaultdict(list)` allows you simply do `newDict[key].append(I)` instead of the ugly `setdefault`.. Lastly, `initialList` isn't really necessary - the first few unkeyed values will just go into `newDict['']`.

Comment: @PaulMcG I thought about using `str.startswith` too but then I saw the OP's other question you pointed out in the comment, where `condition 1` is in the beginning of the string and is followed by other characters, so I decided to use regex to allow the OP to easily tune it to his real needs, knowing that he must've arbitrarily simplified his example input for the question on SO. I had thought about using `defaultdict` too but decided that it's ugly to print in the output, and the OP asks for a dict. Lastly, the OP asks for only `condition`s as keys, so I decided against using `''` as a key.

Comment: @PaulMcG All good points that I had also thought about by the way. I decided to stick to the OP's exact requirements but indeed these are points he should consider when he implements it into his real code.